Can I translate the word "abbreviate" as "ужимать"?
I have read several articles of the word meaning. I think that the translation is adjustable for all of them, isn't it?

Ужимать, while being derived from a word literally meaning "to press, to compress", is almost always used in the metaphorical sense.
One of its meanings is "to shorten, usually by getting rid of everything non-essential and sacrificing quality":


Основу ее составляли второстепенные собрания сочинений, растянутые на манер мехов гармони, которые, если ужать их до одного тома, издают бледный звук лопнувшей струны. [Ирина Полянская. Прохождение тени (1996)]
Один раз можно ужать истину до размеров формулы, а формулу — до размеров остроты. [Михаил Жванецкий. Что такое юмор? (1980-1989)]


In this meaning, it's close to the English "abridge", to which "abbreviate" is an obsolete synonym.
Note that this word is colloquial. In formal situations, the words сжать or сократить are used instead, the latter being the most common translation of "abbreviate".
Technically, you could find a context where you would use ужать to translate "abbreviate". However, the stylistic difference between the two and the shift of the meaning of "abbreviate" make it very hard to find such a context.

its not. abbreviate is сокращать.

public joint stock company gazprom - сокращенно PJSC Gazprom

ужимное has meaning of a thing being squeezed but even then its сжать.

тебе надо сжать резюме до 2 страниц


сжать pdf до 25 мб


From Merriam-Webster's ALED: abbreviate: to make (something) shorter.

@Чёрный Монах No, abbreviate cannot be used in all contexts to mean "to make something shorter". We don't normally say "can you abbreviate your dissertation?" The way to say it is rather "can you produce an abridged version of it?" It's difficult to be overly emphatic as there are 400m native speakers: there are Google hits for "to abbreviate an argument", but only 6 such hits are shown.

@ЧёрныйМонах ok bro im just telling u like it is, u dont have to follow my advice but then ppl will think u speak weird. trust me on this im a native speaker

@pompey1969, how did you find the Google hits?

Well, I put "to abbreviate an argument" (in inverted quotes) into Google, and then got search results. Then if you click on Tools, Google tells you how many hits there were.

You can also try this with "to abbreviate a book". "To abbreviate a book title" makes more sense, however. E.g. you could refer to "Through the Looking-glass and what Alice Found There" as "Through the Looking-glass", and that will be an abbreviated book title.

"Abbreviate" implies cutting a part off to make it smaller, whereas "ужимать" means making smaller without cutting anything essential, so it's compress. You can use this word when talking about a text fragment that can be compressed by re-wording to shorten the length but without losing any meaning or detail.
